# Java data structure representation

Tags: java, data-structures, representation

I'm having quite a bit of problem deciding how to represent a certain problem. Basically, I'll need a list/vector with a given number from `args[1]`. Each of them will have from 0 up till some `args[2]`.

I'll need to make an algorithm to search all possible combinations of arguments from the elements within the first one.

As an example:

```
1 -> 3 5
2 -> 1 3 4 5
3 -> 2
4 -> 2 5 1
5 -> 1 3 4
```

From this example, I'll have to generate all the combination of paths, like from 1 you can go to 3 or 5 and so on and cant go back through the same mini path so I'm guessing I'll have to figure out some recursive way to fully search all paths.

My first attemp was to make a vector for 1 to 5 with arraylist for each element but I'm having problem initializing and accessing values withing the lists.

```
for (int i=0; i < total; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new ArrayList<int>(total);
}

for (int i=0; i < total_paths; i++) {
    matrix[Integer.parseInt(args[i])].add(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such. What's the actual problem you are having initializing and accessing values?

Comment: It says it requires an array but finds a Vector. But I'm thinking I need a n-ary tree to solve this. There isn't any implementation of it in java is it? If not guess I'll have to make a class for it

Comment: Show us the declaration of `matrix`, then - sounds like that's not right...and there's no Vector in the code you've shown us. We need to see more. Oh, and mixing Vector and ArrayList in the same code is a bit odd...just use ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have an `ArrayList<int>`; only an `ArrayList<Integer>`.  However, Java will automatically convert between `int` and `Integer` for you in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `ArrayList<int>` - it has to be `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Lists can only store Objects, such as Integer, String, etc. In Java, `int` is a primitive type, not a true Object.

Your second code block will boil down to:

```
matrix[1].add(1);
```

(for example - the same value as an array index *and* a List entry) - is that what you meant? It's not entirely clear how you are passing the values in...